# Accessing Sharepoint from axis2

Tags: soap

I am trying to write my first SOAP client to access a document library(Test1) that I created in my company sharepoint server. So far I have created the Stubs using axis (1.4) and created the main method; but when I have tried this code it shows me a 401 Not allowed error in the console.

What is the cause? Something misconfigured? Or do I need to ask for special permissions to use the SP API?

```
public static int main() {
  String[] destinationUrls = {"https://[sharepoint host]/[sharepoint site]/Test1"};

  ListsLocator listsLocator = new ListsLocator();
  ListsSoapStub listsStub = (ListsSoapStub) listsLocator.getListsSoap();
  listsStub.setUsername("NotMyDomain\\NotMyUser");
  listsStub.setPassword("NotMyPassword");
  GetListResponseGetListResult result = listsStub.getList("Test1");
  for(MessageElement me : result.get_any()) {
    System.out.println(me.toString());
  }
}
```

As a side note, I do not like having to cast from ListsSoap to ListsSoapStub in order to be able to setup user and password, there is some other method more elegant to do that?

---

Update: It looks like the axis plugin I am using may be a little outdated, would you advise switching to Apache Axis2 plugin?

---

Update2: My axis2 code. The SysAdmin has confirmed that we use NTLM; I had to add the SSL certificate to cacerts and setup the System properties. Yet I get the same error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword"));
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Archivos de programa/Java/jre1.6.0_02/lib/security/cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "notAPassword");

    HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new
    HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
    auth.setUsername ("notMyUser");
    auth.setPassword("notMyPassword");
    auth.setDomain ("DOMAIN");
    auth.setHost("host.domain.com");

    List<String> authPrefs = new ArrayList<String>(1);
    authPrefs.add (AuthPolicy.NTLM);
    auth.setAuthSchemes (authPrefs);

    ListsStub listsStub = new ListsStub("https://host.domain.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx");
    GetListItems getListItems0 = new GetListItems();
    getListItems0.setListName("MyList");
    listsStub.getListItems(getListItems0);
}
```

---

Final Update: 
Ok, this was easier, I only forgot the following line:

```
listsStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
```

Now it works (in the sense that the error appears while processing the SP WS response).

Comment: What's the authentication mechanism used on your SP site? NTLM? Basic? FBA?

Comment: @'Jaap Vossers' I have checked with SA, it is NTLM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut feel says the client is trying to authenticate using Basic auth. Use an http sniffer (like Fiddler) to inspect the http headers to confirm.

I reckon there is some extra work involved getting an Axis (Java) client to talk with a server that uses NTLM (Microsoft) authentication.

Comment: Since you left your comment I have been reading some documentation and probably you are right. Anyway it may take a time for me to confirm it; another of the things that I have found suggest that I should be using axis2 (WebServices) instead of axis (RPC), so it may be a couple of days before I can verify it (be patient).

Comment: I have updated my code, the error still appears.

Comment: I was setting the authentification option but not passing it to the stub. I do not know which of the many mistakes I have found is what caused the original message, but I would have stumbled with the NTLM sooner or later so I'll check it as the correct answer.